# How to @ member

Tags: discord.py

So basically I want to mention a member when they are muted

```
 {member.display_name}
```

When I put the @ around the full thing like

```
 @{member.display_name}
```

It doesn't actually mention the user
Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `{member.mention}`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `@` symbol before `member.name` or `member.display_name` will not actually mention the user. Discord.py has a different variable for calling this event called `member.mention`. `member.mention` will mention the member inside of `member`. Happy coding!

Sincerely,
killrebeest